# Highcharts - Bar - Setting the X axis width and the chart area width to be constant

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Can anyone recommend a method of setting the X axis to be a constant width across multiple instances of a bar chart?

See this jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/LCYwW/1/

The first chart is an example of placing the data for 2 locations in a single chart. In this case, Highcharts automatically adjusts the X axis width to accommodate both location labels.

However, I need to separate these 2 locations into separate charts, but maintain the same proportions of X Axis to bar area width for both charts. See charts 2 and 3 in the example. In this case, Highcharts picks an X axis width that suits just the single location and the 2 charts do not line up when stacked.

Is there a method to get the individual charts to maintain the same proportions as each other? I tried setting the xAxis.labels.style.width attribute, and it does *something*, but doesn't seem to be a concrete width. See http://jsfiddle.net/LCYwW/3/

This example is easiest to see in the jsFiddle, but SO is requiring me to post the code:

```
 $('#containerAll').highcharts({
    chart:{
        type: 'bar'
    },
    series: [
        {
        name: 'Male',
        data: [{"name":"58.1%","y":0.581}, {"name":"18.1%","y":0.181}]
    },
        {
            name: 'Female',
            data: [{"name":"58.5%","y":0.585}, {"name":"28.5%","y":0.285}]   
        }
    ],
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Short Name', 'Much Longer Location Name']   
    }
});


$('#container1').highcharts({
    chart:{
        type: 'bar'
    },
    series: [
        {
        name: 'Male',
        data: [{"name":"58.1%","y":0.581}]
    },
        {
            name: 'Female',
            data: [{"name":"58.5%","y":0.585}]   
        }
    ],
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Short Name'],
        labels: {
            style: {
                width: 200
            }
        }
    }
});

 $('#container2').highcharts({
    chart:{
        type: 'bar'
    },
    series: [
        {
        name: 'Male',
        data: [{"name":"18.1%","y":0.181}]
    },
        {
            name: 'Female',
            data: [{"name":"28.5%","y":0.285}]   
        }
    ],
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Much Longer Location Name'],
        labels: {
            style: {
                width: 200
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a lot more control over the labels if you turn on useHTML.

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Short Name'],
        labels: {
            style: {
                width: '100px',
                'min-width': '100px'
            },
            useHTML : true
        }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LCYwW/5/

You'll also probably have to set a min and max for the yAxis to keep the data in proportion.

Fiddle with the yAxis max set: http://jsfiddle.net/LCYwW/6/

Comment: I don't understand why you need to set both the `width` and `min-width` properties. I couldn't get it to work using just width, so your answer really helped me out. But I don't like not understanding *why* it worked...

Comment: @fotijr I have no idea why highcharts does this, but in the htmlUpdateTransform function they set the width of the label's span to be the declared width only if it's greater than the width of the string.  They don't do any processing on the min-width.  So having both solves the width and the alignment.

Answer (score 5):

Also consider, using the [chart: marginLeft](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.marginLeft) property to set a fixed width for the labels:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            marginLeft: 160
        },
        // ...
    })
});
```

This preserves the other behavior of the chart, e.g., alignment of the labels. Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582294/fixed-y-axis-label-width-in-highcharts).

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `marginLeft` property inside of chart worked like a charm for me.

```
chart: {
  type: 'bar',
  marginLeft: 200
}, ...
```